# Scala 2.10 and package reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

How can I reflect over package hierarchies in Scala 2.10's reflection? Can I find out what subpackages exist, or what the parent packages are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since in general case it's impossible to enumerate packages in a classloader, Scala reflection also doesn't provide this capability. This is unlike the situation with scalac, which is fed a list of directories, which can be enumerated.

Traversing up the hierarchy is easy. Just use `symbol.owner`.

Comment: Are there any changes in Scala 2.12? Are there any possibilities to get sub-packages?